# Java Process error cannot run program

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a command i.e: mvn -version through java but I keep getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn -version": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I know this command works, because I have test it manually. Here is the code which runs the command:

```
public InputStream runCommand() {
        try {

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("mvn -version");
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String s = null;
            while((s = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
            return process.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

Could someone point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First the `mvn` executable will need to be in you search `path` environment, or you will need to specify it's location as part of the command.  `ProcessBuilder` expects the command and parameters to be separated, otherwise it's looking for an executable name `mvn -version`, `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("mvn -version")` should probably be `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("mvn", "-version")`.  I doubt trying to read the output of the process after it's terminated will work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ProcessBuilder("mvn -version")` does not run `mvn` with an argument `-version`, as you're intending. Instead, it tries to run a program named `mvn -version`. That is, the program name itself has two words and a space between them. It makes perfect sense that you don't have such a program! :-)

Notice that ProgramBuilder's constructor [takes a `String...` argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder-java.lang.String...-) for the program name and arguments. What you want is: `new ProcessBuilder("mvn", "-version")`.